# Почему переход осуществляется в любом случае?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть форма  `<form action="page.php" onclick="welcomeAnimate()" method="POST" >`, по идее если `welcomeAnimate()` возвращает `false`, тогда переход page.php не будет. 
Но почему-то в любом случае переход осуществляется

```
 function welcomeAnimate() {
     var enter = document.getElementById("enter")
     var login = document.getElementById("login")
     var password = document.getElementById("password")
     login.style.display = "none"
     var box = [login, password]
     enter.onclick = function () {
         var display = login.style.display
         if (login.value == "" && password.value == "") {
             if (display == "none") {
                 for (var a in box) {
                     box[a].style.display = "block";
                 }
             } else if (display == "block") {
                 for (var a in box) {
                     box[a].style.display = "none";
                 }
             } else {
                 alert("Sorry undefined value")
             }
             return false;
         } else {
             return true;
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовать не `onclick`, а [onsubmit](http://htmlbook.ru/html/attr/onsubmit). И функция, которая обрабатывает форму, должна просто проверять значения (в вашем коде еще какой-то обработчик навешивается)

Answer (score 0):

Не особо дружу с javascript, но может быть onclick="welcomeAnimate()" повешать всё же на кнопку формы? Хотя нее, что-то бред какой-то придумала. :-)

Comment: нет, уже пробовал

Comment: на самом деле всё это безумие подразумевает, что клик bubbl`ится к форме

Answer (score 0):

Привет. Нужно отлавливать event события submit. Реализовать возможно с помощью JQuery, примерно так:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    // проверяем значение поля, если равно 'correct' то возвращаем true, иначе false 
    if ($("input:first").val() == "correct") {
        return true;
    }
       return false;
});
```

Попробуй так, может быть пригодиться :)